# Include files in php app [HEROKU]

Tags: php, heroku, amazon-s3, sendgrid

My app works in localhost, but when I deploy it on heroku I get this error

```
Warning: require(app/classes/sendgrid/sendgrid-php.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /app/index.php on line 10 Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'app/classes/sendgrid/sendgrid-php.php' (include_path='.:/app/.heroku/php/lib/php') in /app/index.php on line 10
```

The structure of my project is :

```
mailer //project name
  |
  |-- footer.php
  |
  |-- header.php
  |
  |-- index.php
  |
  |-- inc
  |    |
  |    |-- style.css
  |
  |-- app
       |
       |-- classes
              |
              |-- app.php
              |
              |-- sendgrid
                     |
                     |-- sendgrid-php.php
                     |
                     |-- ...
```

(In my index.php I'm able to include app.php without problem)

The problem doesn't come from sendgrid because I have the problem also with amazon s3...

Answer (score 1):

Solved, all what you have to do is add `composer.json` file in the root (in the folder named mailer in my case). This file must contain at less `{}`